# Press hardware button programmatically on a Zebra TC25

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, katalon-studio

I'm trying to automatically test a mobile app on Zebra TC25 smartphone. The test has been implemented on the Katalon Studio, but I'm not able to activate `trigger_scan` button:

```
AppiumDriver<?> driver = MobileDriverFactory.getDriver()
driver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.XXXX)
    .withFlag(KeyEventFlag.LONG_PRESS));
```

Comment: Provide more information, pls!

Comment: I have to perform QR scanning from frontal scanner. This action is performed by pressing trigger left/right button... I tried to simulate in katalon Studio this action, but I don't found the right enum related to this action "AndroidKey.XXXX"

Answer (score 1):

The trigger might be one of these [KeyEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent)s: `KEYCODE_BUTTON_L1` or `KEYCODE_BUTTON_R1`.

The [Integrator Guide](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/mobile-computers/handheld/tc25.html) confirms this (despite overriding the hardware key is something else):

> To override the trigger key in an application, create a profile for the application that disables the Barcode input.
>   In the application, use standard APIs, such as `onKeyDown()` to listen for the `KEYCODE_BUTTON_L1` and `KEYCODE_BUTTON_R1` presses.

---

When looking at [io.appium.java_client.android.nativekey.AndroidKey](https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/android/nativekey/AndroidKey.html):

> **BUTTON_L1**
>   `public static final AndroidKey BUTTON_L1`
>   Key code constant: L1 Button key. On a game controller, the L1 button should be either the button labeled L1 (or L) or the top left trigger button.
>
> **BUTTON_R1**
>   `public static final AndroidKey BUTTON_R1`
>   Key code constant: R1 Button key. On a game controller, the R1 button should be either the button labeled R1 (or R) or the top right trigger button.

If any other buttons to try, then it would be all of those generic gamepad buttons.

Comment: I found driver.longPressKeyCode(285). The value is KEYCODE_REFRESH, because I got from app KeyEvent Display.

but the button pressure is not performed, instead is working fine for other value like 25(volume_down)

Comment: @SimoneDell'Accio you could use use a `for` or `while` loop, and trigger all of them in a row while logging, with a little delay added, because it needs to be one of them. That `LONG_PRESS`might be the problem... and with this modifier, it might have a different or no action assigned. Better first try to trigger it with Java than with that Appium abstraction, then port to Appium - or just send me a test device :)

Comment: What if the app emits the gamepad event and not the test?